# The 127th \color does not work on XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, color

The following document

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% !TEX TS-program = XeLaTeX

\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}\color{.}
    \color{red} text

\end{document}
```

Gives me black `text`, instead of red `text`.

Grouping earlier colors will resolve it.
That said, I find it bizarre because it is driver-specific.

I wonder if anyone has a good explanation.

Comment: That's a known problem and has already been discussed on the site.

Comment: Fair enough.   (not enough character...)